# JSoup parsing data from within a tag

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am managing to parse most of the data I need except for one as it is contained within the a href tag and I am needing the number that appears after "mmsi="

```
<a href="/showship.php?mmsi=235083844">Sunsail 4013</a>
```

my current parser fetches all the other data I need and is below.  I tried a few things out the code commented out returns unspecified occasionally for an entry.  Is there any way I can add to my code below so that when the data is returned the number "235083844" returns before the name "Sunsail 4013"?

```
try {
        File input = new File("shipMove.txt");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, null);
        Elements tables = doc.select("table.shipInfo");
        for( Element element : tables )
        {
            Elements tdTags = element.select("td");
            //Elements mmsi = element.select("a[href*=/showship.php?mmsi=]");
            // Iterate over all 'td' tags found
            for( Element td : tdTags ){
                // Print it's text if not empty
                final String text = td.text();
                if( text.isEmpty() == false )
                {
                    System.out.println(td.text());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Example of data parsed and html file [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10846316)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `attr` on an `Element` object to retrieve a particular attribute's value
2. Use `substring` to get the required value if the String pattern is consistent

Code

```
// Using just your anchor html tag
String html = "<a href=\"/showship.php?mmsi=235083844\">Sunsail 4013</a>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// Just selecting the anchor tag, for your implementation use a generic one
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

// Get the attribute value
String url = link.attr("href");

// Check for nulls here and take the substring from '=' onwards
String id = url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1);
System.out.println(id + " "+ link.text());
```

Gives,

```
235083844 Sunsail 4013
```

---

Modified condition in your `for` loop from your code:

```
...
    for (Element td : tdTags) {
                // Print it's text if not empty
                final String text = td.text();
                if (text.isEmpty() == false) {
                    if (td.getElementsByTag("a").first() != null) {
                        // Get the attribute value
                        String url = td.getElementsByTag("a").first().attr("href");

                        // Check for nulls here and take the substring from '=' onwards
                        String id = url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1);
                        System.out.println(id + " "+ td.text());
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println(td.text());
                    }
                }
            }
...
```

The above code would print the desired output.

Comment: sorry, I am really unsure how to add this to my current code. I don't see any difference from prior information unless I change Element link = element.select("a").first(); and then it messes up by printing speed in front of the rest of my results.  I'll edit my question to show the text file and what my current code returns.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly.  When I was adding the attr element I was doing it within the first for loop which is the reason it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you need value of attribute, you should use `attr()` method.

```
for( Element td : tdTags ){
    Elements aList = td.select("a");
    for(Element a : aList){
        String val = a.attr("href");
        if(StringUrils.isNotBlank(val)){
            String yourId = val.substring(val.indexOf("=") + 1);


        }
}
```

Comment: Is it meant to be StringUtils?  If there is any chance you could explain how I can involve this in my current code as I still need the rest of the td elements I'm retrieving.